# Source dependency in Maven multi module project - cannot compile modules by themselves

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi module Maven project where the modules `Foo` and `Bar` are Java packages. `Foo` contains a class that `Bar` inherits from. Both `Foo` and `Bar` has main methods for testing and debugging. The modules reside in folder `Project`

Compiling the entire project using `mvn clean package` works fine. But not compiling with the same command in the `Bar` module.

In `Project` there is a pom.xml containing:

```
...
<module>Foo</module>
<module>Bar</module>
<module>FooBar</module>
...
```

In `Bar` is `pom.xml` that contains:

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>Foo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency> 
    ...
```

When I try to use Maven to compile `Bar` from within the modules folder I get errors that it cannot locate the sibling package `Foo`. Other dependencies that are downloaded works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Im pretty new to Maven and this seems to be a beginners error so I assume there is an easy answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to compile the `Bar` module the artefact `com.example.foo:Foo:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` must be retrieved from at least the local Maven repository.

The artefact is saved in the local repository when executing the goal `install`. As you only execute `clean package` on the whole build this does not happen.

You have to execute `install` or `clean install` on the artefact `Foo` or the whole project. Every time you update the version you also have to rebuild the whole project (or at least the local dependencies).

Comment: So what you are saying is that I need to have a compiled .jar of the `Bar` module in the local repository? Would that be achieved by `mvn clean install` on only that package? Also, when I do a `mvn clean install` on the `Foo` package, would the `Bar` .jag still remain in the local repo? Sorry for all the questions, I don't have the source available right now to test.

Comment: @EinarSundgren Yes, yes (although the Maven term for package is artefact) and yes.